# It's all OK with \arctan... except it doesn't work

Tags: errors

I've just been preparing a presentation in LaTeX, when a strange thing occurred.

Suddenly, I wasn't able to write \arctan with LaTeX. I created an another presentation, just to test if sth's wrong or not.

I typed sth like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\arctan$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when I was trying to add such a frame

```
\begin{frame}
$\arctan$
\end{frame}
```

into the "goal" presentation, it didn't work and it gave me some errors, saying for instance

```
!Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\mathop \end{frame}.
```

I'd of course made sure there are no errors except for this one.

Could sb explain me what's going on? I'd be grateful.

Comment: add \show\arctan directly before the frame in both cases to find out if something redefined it.

Comment: Can you make a MWE that reproduces the error?

Comment: see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) if you need help to construct a MWE.

Comment: LaTeX errors often manifest themselves in the lines after which they happened. Check the immediate vicinity of the problematic `\arctan` frame is there anything before it that looks suspicious? Is it only `\arctan` that does not work or does `\arcsin` also not work? What about `$x$`? What about normal text?